# How do I find all inner cells within a spatial network of nodes?

Tags: python, networkx, polygon, shapely, topology

I have an arbitrary network of nodes. This network could look something like this:

[image]

The nodes of this network have spatial positions, so they cannot be moved or re-organized. Each node has an x coordinate, a y coordinate, and a unique ID. I am using a `networkx.Graph` to store the connections between all the nodes.

```py
import uuid
from dataclasses import dataclass

import networkx
import shapely


@dataclass
class Node:
    x: float
    y: float
    node_id: uuid.UUID

example_node = Node(x=0, y=1, node_id: uuid.uuid4())
G = networkx.Graph()
G.add_node(example_node.node_id.hex, data=example_node)
... # more nodes added
... # connections between nodes added
```

I want to find all cells within this network. Something like:
[image]

```py
def get_graph_cells(G: networkx.Graph) -> list[list[Node]]:
    """ 
    Returns a list of lists, where the outer list is the cells, and the inner 
    list is the Nodes in that cell.
    """
   ...
```

Note that I don't wish to find any outer cells, only the inner ones that have nothing else inside.

I tried looking for different algorithms to solve this but haven't found any. I've looked in the `shapely` and `geonetworkx` libraries and haven't found any methods for this either.

Comment: What do you mean by cell? What would be the desired output for your example graph?

Comment: Does networkx.minimum_cycle_basis give the desired result? eg in graph = networkx.grid_2d_graph(4, 5)
networkx.minimum_cycle_basis(graph)
it finds exactly the 12 small cycles